# Confusion while validating dataset using cross-validation in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

My confusion stems from this image  [image: cross validation example]

found on the Scikit-learn docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html). As far as I understand from this picture is that the entire dataset is split into two train and test sets and cross-validation happens on the training part only. But how do we perform the final evaluation as shown in the picture by the orange box? The docs only show this example

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, random_state=42)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)
scores
```

which would then just output the array of scores of each folds like so `array([0.96..., 1.  ..., 0.96..., 0.96..., 1.        ])`. How do I do the Final evaluation of the originally held-out data kept for final validation as shown by the orange box in the picture? I'm not getting any clear understanding of this from the docs

Comment: The image and the code are out of context here; there is another code snippet using `train_test_split` for producing the training and test sets, applying CV on the training set, and evaluating the performance on the test data `X_test`. But in any case, this is not a *programming* question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help[] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info (applicable also here).

Answer (score -1):

[cross validation schema explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICwhM.png)
The evaluation result of folds [0.85, 0.89, .9, 0.82, ...] are useless if we leave in a table
then, we calculate the average of the evaluations of all the folds (i.e. the average of the table), then, we decide if we pass to the test phase or not yet

the cross-validation is very important (although it is a heavy operation especially with a large data set), it serves to train the model in question on any possible partition of data (and the same for the test),
if we get a good score in cross-validation, it means that our model is well trained on our dataset, which will give a performing model (in general)

Comment: does that mean we need to perform cv on the test data once again? or do we just fit and predict on the test data. When I try to just predict on the test data it scikit learn tells me to fit again...which didn't make sense to me

Comment: No, we do not perform adjustment and CV on the test data 
Why do we do CV for training data?
This is done to perform small tests on each training score at the same time of our model building 

after having obtained a trained model (with CV on the training data), we make predictions directly on the test data

the test data is a simulation of the data used in a production environment

Comment: Please **edit** your answer for clarity; OP is justifiably confused. Try to *answer the question*, and refrain from statements about the importance or difficulty etc of CV.